# Problems installing Thin on windows 7 x86

Tags: windows, ruby, thin

I'm having problems getting [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) working on my Windows 7 machine (I've already installed eventmachine v0.8.1):

> `>`gem install thin --ignore-dependencies
>   checking for main() in -lc... no
>   creating Makefile
>
> make
>   'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Are there not meant to be precompiled binaries available for thin?

Comment: Belongs on Superuser.com!?! **Really?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there aren't any pre-built binaries.

You will need a C compiler installed. If you installed Ruby via the RubyInstaller, that is going to be really easy, if you used the One-Click Installer, it's goint to be a PITA.

See also: [problems installing thin on Windows](http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/2100213/), which contains an answer by the RubyInstaller and One-Click Installer maintainer.

Comment: this answer is right: you need a compiler available which is the same compiler used to build ruby (which is made easier with the devkit)...or you could ask the thin gem developers to release binary extensions for their gem.

Comment: Actually there have been pre-built binaries for Thin since 2008: http://rubygems.org/gems/thin/versions.  Please see the instructions that I included in my answer below.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8466099/330110

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around the lack of precompiled binaries by installing a compiler:

1. I iInstalled [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) to C:\MinGW (see [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Install_the_MinGW_GCC_Compiler_Suite) for installation instructions)
2. I then installed [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) to C:\msys\1.0
3. I then added c:\MinGW\bin and C:\msys\1.0\bin to my %PATH%
4. Finally I ran `gem install thin` and amazingly it all worked!

I hope this helps out some other poor Windows ruby developer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There actually are pre-built binaries for particular versions of Thin but you need to know which ones.  To get the latest pre-built win32 version do the following:

1. Go to the [RubyGems Thin page](http://rubygems.org/gems/thin)
2. Look under the "Versions" section for a version that has "x86-mswin32" to the right of it.  (As of today versions 1.2.11, 1.2.10, etc all have win32 binaries)
3. Run the following following "gem install" command with the version of Thin included with the "-v" flag:

> gem install thin -v 1.2.11

Here are the results from my installation:

```
c:\>gem install thin -v 1.2.11
Successfully installed thin-1.2.11-x86-mswin32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for thin-1.2.11-x86-mswin32... 
Updating ri class cache with 3611 classes... 
Installing RDoc documentation for thin-1.2.11-x86-mswin32...
```

Comment: It looks like the pre-built binaries have not been maintained for over two years, so unless you really want version 1.2.11, you should probably build it yourself still.

Answer (score 0):

A binary for thin is in fact available (and apparently one has been since ver 1.2.2).

However, I couldn't install thin on Windows 7 with Ruby 1.9.2 (p290) because of its dependency on EventMachine.

Running `gem install thin --ignore-dependencies` was what was needed to get thin itself installed.

Just wanted to add this note for some other ruby on Windows user.