# Mongrel with Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel, ruby-1.9

When starting the server, I get this strange error after updating to Ruby 1.9:

"
[BUG] cross-thread violation on rb_gc()
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11) [i386-mswin32]

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
"

My mongrel version is 1.1.6, which should be compatible with Ruby 1.9. I also still have the Ruby 1.8.6 installation, so i assume that for some reason mongrel tries to access that and kills ruby? My rails version is 2.3.4, in case it matters.

Answer (score 5):

I would be suspicious of the comments at your [primary source](http://isitruby19.com/mongrel) -- most of the recent ones are spam comments pointing to links selling shoes or handbags.

Of those who *did* get it working and weren't spammers, note that they advise changing your gem source to `http://gems.rubyinstaller.org` or else using the 1.2.0 prerelease.

Personally, I can't think of any compelling reason to use Mongrel post-2008.  There are so many better options.  Thin, Unicorn, and Passenger are all actively maintained, have been 1.9-compliant for a long time, are faster in the typical benchmarks, and have different strengths in their features and ease of deployment.  Mongrel was a huge step forward when it happened, but now it's a bit of an antique with no distinct advantages.

Just...anything but Webrick.  Really.

Comment: Agree with the post-2008 comment, but still, it should be added that at this point gems.rubyinstaller.org says `Heroku | No such app. There is no app configured at that hostname. Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.`

Answer (score 2):

> which should be compatible with Ruby
>   1.9

Is there something specific that makes you think that? As of a couple of weeks ago, I had established that Mongrel does *not* work with Ruby 1.9 on Windows. I don't believe that Mongrel has been compiled successully with gcc/mingw32, which Ruby 1.9 requires.

The simplest option is to switch back to WEBRick.

It's also fairly straightforward to use [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/), which is comparable to - and possibly faster than - Mongrel. I found I needed to build it though, which will involve installing mingw. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139196/problems-installing-thin-on-windows-7-x86/2146407#2146407) - get ready to build before `gem install thin` and it should all happen OK. Then just use `thin start` instead of `ruby script/server`.

Comment: According to this site (http://isitruby19.com/mongrel) some people have got it working with 1.1.6...

With Webrick i get the following message:
[2010-05-04 16:40:41] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2010-05-04 16:40:41] INFO  ruby 1.9.1 (2010-01-10) [i386-mingw32]
[2010-05-04 16:40:41] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2696 port=3000

In radrails it's shown in red, so not sure if it's normal info or error message. Anyway after that the server is running, but when i try to load the page on browser in stops.

Comment: Ouch, too bad this don't do the line breaks correctly. Hmm, i guess i should try Thin.