# Rails App Runs fine on Mac OS X but mongrel does not answer requests in Windows 7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows, freeze, macos

I'm having some trouble with a Rails app.

When the app is deployed on Mac OS X Snow Leopard with MySQL server 5.1, it runs everything fine. However, when I deploy it on Windows 7 (either 32 or 64 bit) Mongrel receives the request (i can see the GET request on development.log) but nothing happens, and the browser says "waiting for server" forever.

I have tried to install the same version on Windows as I have on the Mac (mysql 5.1) to no avail. I keep getting the same error.

I have checked what happens to the database when i make the GET request using the Mysql Administrator tool. A new connection appears, from the Rails app database role; however, it stays in "sleep" forever and the "Time" column keeps increasing... "It looks like its waiting for something... The next life maybe, who knows?" :P

I am able to migrate the database on windows and even seed the database, but Mongrel wont respond any GET requests...

Does anybody have any idea on what could it be? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch from mongrel to "thin".

[Thin - A fast and simple web server](http://macournoyer.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/thin-a-fast-and-simple-web-server/)

[Problems installing Thin on windows 7 x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139196/problems-installing-thin-on-windows-7-x86) (Stack Overflow)

Comment: It seems to be running. Thanks a lot.